# Как программно поменять стиль приложения

Tags: java, android

В xml можно прописать такой код, для того что бы поменять стиль
`@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar`
Как тоже самое сделать в коде на Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы реализовать смену стиля в настройках - при выборе нужной темы, записывайте ее id в преференсы, и пересоздавайте активити. А в самом активити в методе `onCreate()` вызываете метод `setTheme` с id из преференсов. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
public void changeTheme() {
        PreferencesManager.getInstance().setAppTheme(selected_theme_id);
        restart();
    }


public void restart() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            recreate();
        } else {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

а в `onCreate()` добавляем:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(PreferencesManager.getInstance().getAppTheme());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getActivityResource());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод `setTheme()` в `onCreate()` методе.

например для `Holo`

```
 setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);

 setContentView(R.layout.activity);
```

Comment: Как правильно в коде написать? Желательно в полном объеме опишите.

Comment: Чтобы не было проблем метод сей лучше вызвать до super.onCreate()

Comment: Я хочу сделать что бы в меню настроек было несколько пунктов с настройками стиля,поэтому в onCreate этого сделать не получится. 
как это сделать в методе   onResume?

Comment: @Romag, придется извращаться, чтобы сделать именно в onCreate. По-другому не получится. Перезапускайте, например, Activity после изменения темы